# how to add records to has_many :through association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

```
class Agents << ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :house
end

class Customer << ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :agents
  has_many :houses, through: :agents
end

class House << ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :agents
  has_many :customers, through: :agents
end
```

How do I add to the `Agents` model for `Customer`?

Is this the best way?

```
Customer.find(1).agents.create(customer_id: 1, house_id: 1)
```

The above works fine from the console however, I don't know how to achieve this in the actual application.

Imagine a form is filled for the customer that also takes `house_id` as input. Then do I do the following in my controller?

```
def create 
  @customer = Customer.new(params[:customer])
  @customer.agents.create(customer_id: @customer.id, house_id: params[:house_id])
  @customer.save
end
```

Overall I'm confused as to how to add records in the `has_many :through` table?

Comment: In which controller would you store the function "create" ?

Answer (score 176, accepted):

I think you can simply do this:

```
 @cust = Customer.new(params[:customer])
 @cust.houses << House.find(params[:house_id])
```

Or when creating a new house for a customer:

```
 @cust = Customer.new(params[:customer])
 @cust.houses.create(params[:house])
```

You can also add via ids:

```
@cust.house_ids << House.find(params[:house_id])
```

Comment: FYI: You can't create the associated house unless the parent is already saved.

Comment: That has to be the most elegant solution to this problem I've come across. +1 for you.

Comment: @RicardoOtero I guess we can use `build` istead of `create`?

Comment: @Mischa how should i handle error if  House.find(params[:house_id]) is nill.. i got error of TypeMismatch if params[:house_id] is nil.. i already using rescue.  but is there any better_way..??

Comment: I have observed that using `<<` operator does insertion twice in certain cases. So the `create` method is the best way.

Comment: @Mischa, How to add multiple house details to particular customer at once, above answer shows it for one house pointing one customer.

Answer (score 84):

> **Preface**
>
> This is a strange scenario and I hesitated to answer. It seems like `Agent`s should have many `House`s rather than a one-to-one relationship, and a `House` should belong to just one `Agent`. But with that in mind....

"The best way" depends on your needs and what feels most comfortable/readable to you. Confusion comes from differences in ActiveRecord's behavior of the `new` and `create` methods and the `<<` operator, but they can all be used to accomplish your goal.

#### The `new` Method

`new` will not add an association record for you. You have to build the `House` and `Agent` records yourself:

```rb
# ...
house = @cust.houses.new(params[:house])
house.save
agent = Agent.new(customer: @cust house: house)
agent.save
```

Note that `@cust.houses.new` and `House.new` are effectively the same because you still need to create the `Agent` record in both cases.

(This code looks weird, you can't easily tell what it's supposed to be doing, and that's a smell that maybe the relationships are set up wrong.)

#### The `<<` Operator

As Mischa mentions, you can also use the `<<` operator on the collection. This will only build the `Agent` model for you, you must build the `House` model:

```rb
house = House.create(params[:house])
@cust.houses << house
agent = @cust.houses.find(house.id)
```

#### The `create` Method

`create` will build both `House` and `Agent` records for you, but you will need to find the `Agent` model if you intend to return that to your view or api:

```rb
house = @cust.houses.create(params[:house])
agent = @cust.agents.where(house: house.id).first
```

As a final note, if you want exceptions to be raised when creating `house` use the bang operators instead (e.g. `new!` and `create!`).

Comment: Should the line `agent = @cust.houses.find(house.id)` read `agent = @cust.agents.find(house.id)` instead? The `agent` variable in the "new Method" is different to the `agent` in the latter examples. Might create some confusion for people working with additional attributes on the join table.

Comment: can you elaborate on retrieving data from the joint table Agents without having N+1 bug 
example displaying all the houses and corresponding agents for the given customer

Answer (score 6):

Another way to add associations is by using the foreign key columns:

```
agent = Agent.new(...)
agent.house = House.find(...)
agent.customer = Customer.find(...)
agent.save
```

Or use the exact column names, passing the ID of the associated record instead of the record.

```
agent.house_id = house.id
agent.customer_id = customer.id
```