# How to create join table record in Rails, has many: through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Classes `user` and `event` have a `has many: through`relationship.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_events
  has_many :events, :through => :user_events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_events
  has_many :users, :through => :user_events
end
```

In my event controller I'd like to create a record for User_events, which I do right now with the following:

```
def create
  @event = Event.new(event_params)
  @user = User.find(current_user.id)
  @user_events = User.user_events.create
  @user_events.user_id = @user.id
  @user_events.event_id = @event.id
end
```

This feels heavy though so I figure there's a better, more "Rails way" of doing it. What's the correct way?

Comment: for an extended response, see `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297338/how-to-add-records-to-has-many-through-association-in-rails#answer-18114492`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def create
  @event = Event.new(event_params)
  if @event.save
    @event.users << current_user
    redirect_to event_path(@event)
  else
    render action: :new
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def create
  @event = Event.new(event_params)
  @event.users.add(User.find(current_user.id))
  @event.save # I guess that you want to save the relation
end
```

Comment: I like this answer but I get an error: undefined method `add' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>

Comment: Ok. Try the new answer. I guessed wrong that you had an User entity in current_user.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what params are bringing and how they are formatted. If it's a form submission and it's bringing a user_id, you should be able to just create the event

user = User.find(params[:user_id])
user.events << Event.new(params[:event])

If you'd like to add it to the current_user:

```
current_user.events << Event.new(params[:event])
```

As you see it all depends on how the params are being passed and where you're getting the user from.

Those are a few options.