# Creating joined records using has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through

Ok I thought I was following this answer pretty well... [how to add records to has_many :through association in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297338/how-to-add-records-to-has-many-thro%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bugh-association-in-rails). But clearly not.

**Model code:**

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :request
  has_many :transactories
  has_many :inventories, through: :transactories
end

class Inventory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :transactories
  has_many :transactions, through: :transactories
end

class Transactory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :inventory
  belongs_to :transaction
end
```

I'm basically trying to match inventories with transactions (people who have stuff, with people who want that stuff)

**Here's the flow I'm trying to achieve:**

1. User provides data in a hash where key = the `itemlist_id` of what they want and the value = the `quantity` of that `itemlist_id` that they want. Let's say user wants two of 9, that would look like this: `{ 9 => 2}`
2. For each `itemlist_id` in the user provided hash, I'm going to look inside the `Inventories table` and pull out the `inventory_ids` where the `itemlist_id` matches what the user is looking for and the owner of that `inventory_id` is not the user him or herself. Let's say that in the `Inventories table`, there are 3 ids that fulfill this: `[X, Y, Z]`
3. Now what I'd like to do is create the `Transactions` and associate the `Transactions` and `Inventories` with each other. The outcome of this step is two-fold (I think it's easier to write from the perspective of what the view will look like:

   - that the owner of each X, Y, and Z `inventory_id` should see that there are 2 `transactions` for their item (so they can pick which one they want to honor)
   - that the user can see that for each of their 2 `transactions`, there are notifications to the owners of each X, Y, and Z

**Code to create the associations**

```
# Assume overarching parent request has been created, called @requestrecord
# Step 1, @transactionparams = { 9 => 2 }
@transactionparams.each do |itemlist_id, quantity|
# Step 2 matched_inventory_id = [X,Y,Z] 
      matched_inventory_id = Inventory.where.not(signup_id: @requestrecord.signup.id).where(itemlist_id: itemlist_id).ids 
# Step 3, 2 transactions created each with itemlist_id of 9, each associated with inventory_ids X, Y, Z. In turn, inventory_ids X, Y, Z each associated with each of the two transactions created
      quantity.to_i.times do
        transaction = @requestrecord.transactions.create(itemlist_id: itemlist_id) 
        transaction.inventories.create matched_inventory_id
      end
    end
```

Step 3 is tripping me up. The code is stuck at the `transaction.inventories.create` line and I'm getting an error: `uninitialized constant Transaction::Transactory`

UPDATE

Now I'm stuck at the error `You tried to define an association named transaction on the model TransactionInventory, but this will conflict with a method transaction already defined by Active Record. Please choose a different association name.` I tried specifying `class_names` and `foreign_keys`, see example below:

```
belongs_to :transaction, foreign_key: "transaction_id", class_name: "Transaction"
```

Comment: try changind your model's name for any other since Transaction is used for ActiveRecord, http://thesaurus.com/browse/transaction

Comment: This was the final solution. Damnit, I wish Rails automatically warned you against creating things with words they're already using....

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a loading issue, it is possible that in production your code without any modification would work because of eager loading. Anyhow you could try this to fix your issue:

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :request
  has_many :transactories, class_name: 'Transactories'
  has_many :inventories, through: :transactories
end

class Inventory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :transactories, class_name: 'Transactories'
  has_many :transactions, through: :transactories
end

class Transactories < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :inventory, class_name: 'Inventory'
  belongs_to :transaction, class_name: 'Transaction'
end
```

It's a bit too much to specify `class_name` for each and every of your `has_many` like I suggest, but its "safe".

And perhaps after you confirm that solution works you should be able to remove `class_name` from most of your `has_many` and keep it only for `Transaction.transactories` relation

Comment: Ok now it's telling me `You tried to define an association named transaction on the model Transactories, but this will conflict with a method transaction already defined by Active Record. Please choose a different association name.`

Comment: OK so if I change depluralize into `class_name: "Transactory"` I go back to the error `uninitialized constant Transaction::Transactory`

Comment: Hi when I try to upvote this answer I get a downvote instead... what are you getting? Sorry... I'd like to upvote this because this was part of the solution

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a wrong assignment in

```
transaction.inventories.create matched_inventory_id
```

And by the way it should be `matched_inventory_ids` because the `ids` method returns allways an array

The `others.create` method does not accept id or an id's array. It will accept attributes of the  inventory in that case

To do association by id use the `other_ids` method

```
transaction.inventory_ids = transaction.inventory_ids + matched_inventory_ids
```

Comment: Ok this is really close to getting me there! Quick question though, should I expect this to create a two way relationship? I mean that using this code, I can see that transaction has many inventories indeed, but if I take each of `matched_inventory_id` and I query for their transactions, I get nothing. Now that I know the syntax I can create it, but it just makes sense to me that since this is many-to-many they should have already been created.

Comment: Yes. As it's many-to-many going through a join table it cannot be one way per definition

Comment: Interesting, so then I'll play around with it a little bit more to see why it's not working so far.

Comment: Wrong query i guess. After having assigned inventory_ids to transaction,  call `Inventory.find(inventory_ids.first).transactions`. It will return all the transaction of the first inventry_id, including the current transaction

Comment: That gave me a no method error for `inventory_ids`. But anyways, it was a typo and I got it working, I can use Inventory.find_by_id(id).transactions. In any case, this is great, I'll upvote this, can't mark as a check because technically it's not the answer to the specific problem I asked...but once I solved that problem, this was the answer to the second part problem that would have emerged, which is that my code to associate the records was wrong. (and frankly NO ONE knew how to do this... all the answers I got on my other question were around creating... not associating after creation)