# rails add record to has_many :through join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join

```
class EventTeam < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :team
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :event_teams
  has_many :teams, through: :event_teams
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :event_teams
  has_many :events, through: :event_teams
end
```

I am trying to add the :event_id and :team_id to the EventTeam join table when creating a new Event and can't seem to figure out how, despite an exhaustive search of similar questions such as: [how to add records to has_many :through association in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297338/how-to-add-records-to-has-many-through-association-in-rails) (I've tried all of these suggestions)

It seems that the following should work, though a NoMethodError is delivered: "undefined method `events' for #ActiveRecord::Relation []"

EventsController

```
def new
  @event = Event.new(:team_id => params[:team_id])
end

def create
  @team = Team.where(:id => params[:team_id])
  @event = @team.events.create(event_params)
  if @event.save
    flash[:success] = "Event created!"
    redirect_to @event
  else  
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

I have a similar situation in the same app with Users, Teams, and Memberships (join table). The following code automatically adds the :team_id and :user_id to the Memberships table when a user creates a new Team.

TeamsController

```
def new
  @team = Team.new(:user_id => params[:user_id])
end

def create
  @team = current_user.teams.create(team_params)
  if @team.save
    flash[:success] = "Team created!"
    redirect_to @team
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> undefined method `events' for #ActiveRecord::Relation []

`where` returns an ***AR relation*** not a ***single instance***, so `@team.events` won't work. Use `find` instead

```
@team = Team.find(params[:team_id])
@event = @team.events.create(event_params)
```

***Update***

> could not find Team with 'id'=

You are getting `team_id` inside `event` hash, so `params[:team_id]` won't work. You need to use `params[:event][:team_id]`

```
@team = Team.find(params[:event][:team_id])
@event = @team.events.create(event_params)
```

Comment: for some reason, I get the error "could not find Team with 'id'=       When I just put 1 instead of params[:team_id], the event is created, and record added to the join table - so .find instead of .where definitely works. The strange part is, I can see team_id=1 in the url for the new_event path.

Comment: @ncarroll What are the params that are generated for that action?

Comment: {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"EryBDSRyQWO3zEXCjjz0J/Y9IOy0bfCw5tVhMnN+MiG0cOyJYWIWPNVihVbyP9C36raLXZ8B2uN8HR9PlCqTzg==",
 "event"=>{"date"=>"2016-04-20",
 "name"=>"test",
 "location"=>"test",
 "venue"=>"test",
 "team_id"=>"1"},
 "commit"=>"Create event"}

Comment: @ncarroll I've updated my answer. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Just specify first value of the relation, since you are searching by unique index with value `id`, so that should be well:

```
@team = Team.where(id: params[:team_id]).first
@event = @team.events.create(event_params)
```

That is because `.where`, unlike `find_by` or `find(1)` returning a `Relation`, not a first value in it.

However, in modern version of rails I saw recommendation to use exactly `where.first` pair, not a `find`.